# Routing problem after upgrading from LTS 8 to LTS 9 (RealURL -> Core routing)

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, realurl, symfony-routing

After migrating our site from version 8 LTS to version 9 LTS, I have some configuration problems with the routing.

With RealURL we use the fixedPostVars, 'noMatch' => 'bypass'.

For example with this URL

```
http://Mysite/my-page/mysubpage
?tx_extension[action]=show
&tx_extension[controller]=Researchers
&tx_extension[fullName]=FirstNameWithÉ-LastName
&tx_extension[id]=37
&cHash=f077e6ab99d456c1d0431603186c32cf
```

We would like to have

```
http://Mysite/my-page/mysubpage/FirstNameWithC-LastNameWithe/37
```

For now I can get

```
http://Mysite/my-page/mysubpage/FirstNameWith%2527-LastName/37
?tx_extension%5Baction%5D=show
&tx_extension%5Bcontroller%5D=Researchers
&cHash=067d606ab30ace24e7cf347bdf89b011
```

I tried several configurations without success.

So how can I do to hide the controller, the action and the cHash.

Also, how to handle accented characters in URL.

This is my configuration for routeEnhancers

```
  ListResearchers:
    type: Plugin
    limitToPages:
      - 2706
      - 2707
    routePath: '/{name}/{uid}'
    namespace: 'tx_extension'
    _arguments:
      name: 'fullName'
      uid: 'id'
```

Comment: Sound to me, like you wanna configure a `type: Extbase` instead of `type: Plugin`... https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html#extbase-plugin-enhancer

Comment: You are right.  This config works but the hash is present
  ListResearchers:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 2706
      - 2707
    extension: ExtensionName
    plugin: PluginName
    routes:
      - routePath: '/{nom}/{uid}'
        _controller: 'Researchers::show'
        _arguments:
          nom: 'fullName'
          uid: 'id'

Comment: Any hints how to disable cHash in URL?

Comment: If the cHash is still present, any (default) parameter is still missing or undefined.

Comment: `fullName` has a too huge value space to be there without `requirements`/`aspects`. That will produce cHash. In your case (string), you should use the `PersistedAliasMapper` or write a custom aspect. `uid` will need `requirements` (if you want to use it. You could get rid of it with `PersistedAliasMapper`)

Comment: You were right @JonasEberle, giving each parameters an aspect and requirement hide the cHash.

Comment: Very good. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fullName` has a too huge value space to be there without `requirements`/`aspects`. That will produce `?cHash`.

In your case (string), you can use the `PersistedAliasMapper` or write a custom aspect.

`uid` will need `requirements`. (If you want to use it. You could get rid of it with `PersistedAliasMapper`)